# Pandas: tz_convert using apply returns object rather than datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe indexed by timestamps in UTC, along with 2 columns specifying the time zone and daylight savings offsets in minutes from UTC:

```
                           time_zone  daylight_saving
END_DATE
2017-06-02 00:00:00+00:00          0               60
2017-06-02 01:00:00+00:00          0               60
2017-06-02 02:00:00+00:00          0               60
2017-06-02 03:00:00+00:00          0               60
2017-06-02 04:00:00+00:00          0               60
```

I'm attempting to convert the timestamps to the local timezone by using pytz.FixedOffset. Using a static offset works fine, I get a datetime with the appropriate timezone:

```
In [51]: df.tz_convert(pytz.FixedOffset(120))[['time_zone','daylight_saving']].head()
Out[51]:
                           time_zone  daylight_saving
END_DATE
2017-06-02 02:00:00+02:00          0               60
2017-06-02 03:00:00+02:00          0               60
2017-06-02 04:00:00+02:00          0               60
2017-06-02 05:00:00+02:00          0               60
2017-06-02 06:00:00+02:00          0               60

In [52]: df.tz_convert(pytz.FixedOffset(120))[['time_zone','daylight_saving']].head().index
Out[52]:
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-02 02:00:00+02:00', '2017-06-02 03:00:00+02:00',
               '2017-06-02 04:00:00+02:00', '2017-06-02 05:00:00+02:00',
               '2017-06-02 06:00:00+02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]', name='END_DATE', freq=None)
```

In order to do this using the offset columns, however, I need to use the apply method:

```
In [63]: r_df.apply(lambda r: 
r['END_DATE'].tz_convert(pytz.FixedOffset(r['time_zone'] + 
r['daylight_saving'])), axis=1).head()
Out[63]:
0    2017-06-02 01:00:00+01:00
1    2017-06-02 02:00:00+01:00
2    2017-06-02 03:00:00+01:00
3    2017-06-02 04:00:00+01:00
4    2017-06-02 05:00:00+01:00
dtype: object
```

As you can see in the output, this returns an object series, not a datetime series as I expected.

If I try to convert it back using pd.to_datetime, I am forced to return it to UTC, defeating the purpose of applying the timezone.

Is there any way to convert this back to a dt while retaining the tz info?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled onto the same issue and reported it to the Pandas community, who redirected me to an older issue referencing the same problem. Sadly there is still no solution to the issue, but if you would like to track the issue you can check out:

1. [The issue I reported.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26041)
2. [The issue I was redirected to.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24020)

Comment: Can you include the solution here (or at least a general guideline/explanation)? The link might break and the solution lost.

Comment: There is still no solution (I should have specified) and copying the whole GitHub issue seems like a waste. Should I convert the answer to a comment under lgg's question?

Comment: Sometimes the lack of a possible solution is a conclusion to the OP's question. You can edit your answer to explain that there is no current solution for the time being and keep this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue today in the exact same situation.

Found a workaraund by chaining the call to tz_convert with dt.tz_localize(tz=None).

```
# function to apply
def tz_func(x):
    return x.dt.tz_convert(x.name).dt.tz_localize(tz=None)
# group by timezone and transform with function
r_df.groupby("time_zone")["END_DATE"].transform(tz_func)
```

Then the resulting series will be of datetime type and not object, since having localized dates produces the pd.Series with type "object".